# Automating complete testing of Java EE web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, automation

I have a doubt. Say I have a web application which is big and relies on Java/Java EE (JSP/Servlets).

Every time before a drop we test each and every functionality on GUI so that everything is working properly. Previously it was easy but now as the number of modules has increased exponentially, manually testing each and every GUI with required functionality is no more a feasible option.

I am on lookout for tools in which I can write my entire test case say about 1000 and then just run it once before the drop and it will list down all the test cases that have failed.

The tool preferably must be free to download and use it.

I dont know whether using

> Arquilian

or

> JUnit

in this regard will help or not but automating testing before the drop is really needed.. 
Please guide.

Comment: Are you testing your front end? Then [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Use Junit together with a mock framework i.e Mockito to test units (service methods)

Use Arquillian to test on an integration level ( how different services, modules work together )

Use a database testing tool (i.e [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/)) to test your database / persistence layer)

Use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) to test your frontend

Test as much as possible.

Use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) and [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) to track your build process and your quality of tests and code

You should always test your application on different level. There is not just one solution. 
Use unit testing to test small pieces of your application and to make refactoring as easy as possible.

Use integration test to check your modules still work together as expected.

Use GUI testing to check if your customers can work with your software.

If its relevant, think about performance testing (i.e. [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) )

Answer (score 1):

Definitively Selenium.
 Couple it with maven cause you will probably need to package your project specifically for testing purpose. Moreover maven allow you to launch a container during the integration-test phase and to close it automatically at the end. You can also configure this as a nightly build on jenkins / hudson so you will be quicly notified of any regression.

Comment: Using selenium, my application relies on JSF. It is not able to record all the inputs values. I am using Selenium integrated in Firefox.. Can you please tell if it possible to integrate Selenium with JSF.

Comment: Yes selenium work with any browser based IHM (Html / JS) whatever is the underlying server technology. You may have some issues due to JS handling, you will have to properly configure your web driver and maybe manually edit your automation script to handle properly some asynchronous behaviors

Comment: That will essentially mean I need to write the entire Selenium test case for each of my GUI. This is because each GUI contains some component which remains hidden at the time of page rendering and appear on page only when certain conditions are met. Also JSF is notorious in appending the ID of form to each component. This becomes even more tougher if the ID is not at all assigned to component as JSF assigns a random generated unique ID to component in case ID is not provided.